# MATLAB switch case with cell array of strings

Tags: string, matlab, exception, switch-statement, cell-array

Is there a way to use a `switch` statement in MATLAB to operate on a cell array of strings such that the first case statement whose string argument matches any of the strings in the cell array is executed?

The context of this problem is in handling errors in a `catch` block.

Suppose that I'm trying to load an image file:

```
path = 'c:\where my files are located';
format = 'MRIm%03d.dcm';

try
    firstheader = dicomread(fullfile(path, sprintf(format, 1)));
catch ex
    % extract last segment of exception identifier
    idSegLast = regexp(ex.identifier, '(?<=:)\w+$', 'match');

    switch idSegLast
        case 'noFileOrMessagesFound'
            disp('No File Or Messages Found');
            return;
        case 'fileNotFound'
            disp('File Not Found');
            return;
        otherwise
            rethrow(ex);
    end
end
```

The `switch` statement in the code above doesn't work because idSegLast is a cell array of strings. Most of the time idSegLast only has one element, but it could potentially have more than one element if multiple exceptions are thrown.

Of course the switch statement above (which doesn't work) can be replaced with the following if-else block, which implements the desired behavior:

```
if (strcmp(idSegLast, 'noFileOrMessagesFound'))
    disp('No File Or Messages Found');
    return;
elseif (strcmp(idSegLast, 'fileNotFound'))
    disp('File Not Found');
    return;
else
    rethrow(ex);
end
```

However, as additional exception handling is added to the code, it will inevitably become less readable than a `switch`-`case` construct would be. I'm always trying to improve the quality of my code and its readability. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure that your implementation with `if` works as intended?. Because as far as I can see `if ([1;0])` is evaluated as false

Comment: What's the problem with the `if-else` option? It's absolutely readable.

Comment: And for @NoelSeguraMeraz question, I suppose that you want to write `if any(strcmp(....))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ismember` together with a list of the exceptions you want to track to parse the cellstring `idSegLast`. It's clumsy, but it seems to work for me.

```
switch num2str(ismember({'noFileOrMessagesFound', 'fileNotFound'}, ...
        idSegLast))
    case '1  0'
        disp('No File Or Messages Found');
        return;
    case '0  1'
        disp('File Not Found');
        return;
    case '1  1' % don't know if it's  possible, but better safe than sorry
        disp('No File Or Messages Found and File Not Found');
        return;
    otherwise
        rethrow(ex);
end
```